# XPath for paragraph following a header?

Tags: html, xml, web-scraping, xpath, screen-scraping

This is the Page Code

```html
<div class="product-description">
                                    <h2>O que é Cicatri Renov ?</h2>
<p>Nada como ter um leave-in de tratamento como aliado para reparar os danos do cabelo. Cicatri Renov além de ser um reparador para cabelos danificados, também serve como protetor térmico. Sua fórmula conta com 10 principais benefícios que os fios necessitam:&nbsp;</p>
<ol>
<li>Reparação instantânea;&nbsp;</li>
<li>Selagem das pontas;&nbsp;</li>
<li>100% mais brilho;&nbsp;</li>
<li>Maciez profunda;&nbsp;</li>
<li>Toque deslizante;&nbsp;</li>
<li>Desembaraço imediato;&nbsp;</li>
<li>10x menos quebra;</li>
<li>Antifrizz;</li>
<li>Antiumidade;</li>
<li>Proteção térmica.</li>
</ol>
<h2>Para que serve o Cicatri Renov?</h2>
<p>O leave-in Elseve pode ser utilizado em todos os tipos de cabelo, atendendo principalmente os danificados. Traz proteção, reparação e revitalização aos fios. Pode ser usado com o cabelo seco ou molhado, antes ou depois do secador.</p>
<h2>Benefícios</h2>
<ul>
<li>O Leave-In Cicatri Renov faz uma plástica capilar instantânea nos fios, sem pesar.</li>
<li>Sela as pontas duplas e o frizz.</li>
<li>Repara instantaneamente, com um toque deslizante.</li>
<li>Proteção térmica.</li>
</ul>
<h2>Como usar o Cicatri Renov?</h2>
<p>Distribua uma pequena quantidade nos fios secos ou úmidos, do comprimento às pontas. Não enxágue!</p>
<p><strong>Dica:</strong> Como proteção térmica, pode ser usado antes ou depois de escova ou chapinha.</p>
<h2>Precaução</h2>
<ul>
<li>Caso o produto caia nos olhos, lave-os imediatamente com água.</li>
<li>Mantenha fora do alcance de crianças.</li>
</ul>
<h2>Composição</h2>
<p>Aqua/water, Dimethicone, Cetearyl Alcohol, Phenyl Trimethicone, Amodimethicone, Quaternium-33, Phenoxyethanol, Steareth-20, Acetic Acid, Ppg-1 Trideceth-6, Behentrimonium Methosulfate, Trideceth-5, Trideceth-10, Polyquaternium-37, Chlorhexidine Digluconate, Dimethiconol, Limonene, Linalool, Benzyl Salicylate, Benzyl Alcohol, Propylene Glycol Dicaprilate/dicaprate, 2-oleamido-1,3-octa-decanediol, Alpha-isomethyl Ionone, Geraniol, Cetyl Alcohol, Citronellol, Citral, Hexyl Cinnamal, Glycerin, Glyceryl , Linoleate, Glyceryl Oleate, Glyceryl Linoleate, Parfim/ Fragrance.</p>                                </div>
```

I want to make an XPath for Octoparse. I want to make an XPath that only selects a text that matches a specific heading. In my case it is `"Composição"` and the text is under the `<p>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//p[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::h2][.='Composição']]
```

will select all `p` elements whose immediately preceding sibling is an `h2` element with string value of `"Composição"`.